# cannot convert the series to <class 'float'> Error while using one module

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
     bprice    cprice  strike  irate  tleft
0    26436.90   91.70   26400     10    0.5
1    26423.00   98.90   26400     10    0.5
2    26436.00   90.00   26400     10    0.5
3    26416.35  103.60   26400     10    0.5
```

I am applying one function ( http://code.mibian.net/ )

`c = mibian.BS([1.4565, 1.45, 1, 30], callPrice=0.0359)`   on my dataframe,

```
df2['IV'] = df2.apply(lambda df: mb.BS([df2['bprice'],26400,10,df2['tleft']],
                                 callPrice=df2['cprice']).impliedVolatility, axis=1)
```

But I am getting the error

> TypeError: ("cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>", 'occurred at index 0')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you wrap the function an do something like this -

```
def my_func(x):
    return mb.BS([x['bprice'], 26400, 10 x['tleft']],
        callPrice=x['cprice']).impliedVolatility

df2['IV'] = df2.apply(my_func, axis=1)
```

In the way you implemented in your code, you actually called `mb.BS` with columns (pd.Series) from the dataframe. See pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) documentation here.

Comment: It worked. Can you tell me why my way, it was throwing an error and your's worked? What was the reason of error?

Comment: @saurabh I added a comment in the answer